# Trying to merge different files csv and to label the columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get a single dataset by merging several cvs files within one folder. So I would like to merge the different file, which each have 4 columns. I would also like to label the four columns using names=[] in pd.concatenate.
I'm using this code:

```
path = r'C:\Users\chiar\Desktop\folder' # defining the path
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_files), ignore_index=True, names=['quat_1', 'quat_2', 'quat_3', 'quat_4'])
```

The problem is that instead of getting 4 columns I get 25, and I don't get labeling.
Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parameter `names` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) if no header in files:

```
name = ['quat_1', 'quat_2', 'quat_3', 'quat_4']
df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f, names=names) for f in all_files), ignore_index=True)
```